Getting error form starting a image in virtualbox '/sbin/vboxconfig'
Package linux-headers-6.8.8-060808-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'linux-headers-6.8.8-060808-generic' has no installation candidate

You've not provided any Ubuntu product or release details; but the kernel mentioned in your question is only a testing kernel and not a supported kernel for Ubuntu; what are you running?  Its common for testing kernels to be abandoned as soon as they start testing the next potential candidate; you need to follow instructions from where it comes & especially note their warnings!

The kernel mentioned in your question is only a testing kernel and not a supported kernel for Ubuntu. The corresponding supported kernel can be installed by running the following commands.
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install linux-headers-generic
sudo reboot

